# How do I dynamically set a file source based on a property in WIX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

We have four regions (dev, test, qa, prod) that all require environment specific config files.  I am trying to develop a WIX install that will accept a property assignment from the msiexec command line and dynamically set the file source of a config file.  I've tried just about everything and read about every page and I can't seem to make it work.  This seems like a trivial probleml.

Answer (score 3):

While there are probably ways to pull off what you ask, the traditional approach would be to include all four files, with their respective components conditioned such that your command line property selects exactly one of them to be installed.